# Call Array Dynamically in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic

I have a map of the US with all 50 states as clickable buttons, when the user clicks a state I want to display information about that state, calling on that state's array dynamically. Below is my own weak attempt that obviously does not work.

```
var stateList = new Array("AK","AL","AR","AZ","CA","CO","CT","DC","DC2","DE","FL","GA","GU","HI","IA","ID",
        "IL","IN","KS","KY","LA","MA","MD","ME","MH","MI","MN","MO","MS","MT","NC","ND","NE","NH","NJ","NM","NV","NY",
        "OH","OK","OR","PA","PR","RI","SC","SD","TN","TX","UT","VA","VT","WA","WI","WV","WY");

function listenerForI( i ) {
    document.getElementById(stateList[i])
    .addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
        stateSelect(stateList[i]);
    }, false);
}

for (var i = 0; i < stateList.length; i++) {
   listenerForI( i );
}

var HIdat = new Array(20,28,50,2) //one array for all 50 states COdat, AKdat, etc.

function stateSelect(state){
    var display_data1 = state + "dat[0]";
    alert(display_data1);
}
```

Should I use eval()? I've heard of something you can do with a global "window[]" but I don't understand how that would work.

Comment: If you ever ask yourself *"Should I use eval?"*, the answer is usually *"No."*. If you ever ask yourself *"Should I use the global window?"*, the answer is usually *"No."*. ;o)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should store the state arrays in their own object:

```
var stateData = {
    HI: [1, 2, 3],
    IL: [4, 5, 6],
    ...
};

var myData = stateData[state];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `window` is an option, like this:

`window[state + "dat"]` will get you the array.

But I would suggest ... exactly what SLaks just posted, so do that instead.

Comment: that works but is such bad codin practice i have to downvote it =P. well i guess ill leave the downvote out.. but yea its not good

Comment: @claud Not cool...  I was going to suggest @SLaks solution but he beat me to it.  Thought it was still good for him to understand how you can get variables in two ways `.something` and `['something']`, which is useful in certain situations.

Comment: Hah, @Slaks sorry for the name misspell, my fingers just want to type a c before a k...

Comment: @kingjiv: hm i don't see how your answer shows the diff between `.something` and `['something']`. i say it's bad practice cause you'd be creating a bunch of global vars and accessing them dynamically (basically doing `eval`) instead of putting it neatly in one array

Comment: @claudiu yup, like I said, I agree the single object is better.  But since he said "I've heard of something you can do with a global 'window[]'" I figured it was worth explaining.  Wasn't complaining about the objection, just the downvote.  And it's definitely not eval.

Comment: @kingjiv: ah yea i didnt downvote cause seemed not appropriate. ill have to get back to you on the eval thing, i forgot the point i wanted to make

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, global vars are members of the window object, so you can use the array indexing syntax to get at them without using `eval`, which is generally to be avoided, like so:

```
function stateSelect(state) {
    var display_data1 = window[state + "dat"];
    alert(display_data1);
}
```